# How can I convert PDF to DOC while maintaining the formating?

Tags: pdf

I want to convert a PDF file to DOC keeping the formatting. I found [an article explaining how to do this with KWord](http://web.archive.org/web/20160513140127/https://embraceubuntu.com/2007/04/10/convertimport-from-pdf-and-keep-the-formatting/), but when I installed KWord I got Caligra Words.

Import doesn’t support PDF files. Should I install an extra plugin for this extension, or install an older version of KWord?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the online service [zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com)

You can even email your file to doc@zamzar.com

Depending on the complexity of the formating there might bee some losses though.

Comment: I can't this file is top secret

Answer (score 1):

You can use google drive - during uploading, check option "convert sent files to google format" (or similar, my languge is Polish).

Yo can also check other online tools - such as http://www.pdftoword.com/ (untested by me).

EDIT:
You can also use LibreOffice Draw. This program can open PDF files, and you will able to edit them.

Comment: I don't want to use on-line converters. my language is also Polish :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your pdf is a one-page document, the best I found is Inkscape. It won't be able to save as a doc but you can edit it.

Unfortunately you can only do this one page at a time.

Comment: I have more than 100 pages to convert

Answer (score 0):

I found a [PDF converter](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-convert-word/), which can convert PDF to MS Word Document, JPEG, TIFF and other formats. I think it’s very powerful.